# How to replace old dictionary with new dictionary, python programming

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have made a program that shows results, adding results and removing results. My problem is that I can remove parts of my dictionary (that is in a file) but I cannot replace my old mith my new. I have tried so many things but nothing works. In other words, I have file that contains information about results. I want to remove a name (in this case it is q, w or e. In my fucntion def remove, i print my new list but and the remove worked but the new uptades list with names and results doesn't replace the old, def print_result. I cannot get this to work, I have tried so many things and help would be much appriciated  Sorry for the swedish words.

```
result.txt = (q;1;1;1
w;1;1;1
e;1;1;1)

def main():
    results = get_results()

    while True:

        print_menu()

        try:
            menu_choice = int(input("Val: "))
            if menu_choice == 1:
                print_result(results)
            elif menu_choice == 2:
                add_results(results)
            elif menu_choice == 3:
                remove_results(results)
            elif menu_choice == 4:
                save_result_to_file(results)
                break
            else:
                print("Ogiltligt val, välj en siffra mellan 1 - 4, tack!")
        except ValueError:
            print("Ogiltligt val, välj en siffra mellan 1 - 4, tack!")


def get_results():
    results_list = []

    try:
        results_file = open("result.txt", "r")
        results = results_file.read()

        for i in results.split("\n"):
            if i != "":
                result_info = i.split(";")
                results_list.append({
                    "namn": result_info[0],
                    "varv1": result_info[1],
                    "varv2": result_info[2],
                    "varv3": result_info[3]
                })

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Det gick inte att hitta filen!")
    except IndexError:
        print("Inga tillagda namn!")

    return results_list

def save_result_to_file(results):
    results_file = open("result.txt", "w")

    for result in results:
        results_file.write("{};{};{};{}\n".format(result["namn"], result["varv1"], result["varv2"], result["varv3"]))

        remove_results(results)

    results_file.close()

def print_result(results):
    print("Resultat")
    print("-"*10)

    print("")
    for result in results:
        print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(result["namn"], result["varv1"], result["varv2"], result["varv3"], end=""))
    print("")

def add_results(results):
    while True:
        try:
            results.append({
                "namn": input("Namn: "),
                "varv1": int(input("Varv 1: ")),
                "varv2": int(input("Varv 2: ")),
                "varv3": int(input("Varv 3: "))
                })
        except ValueError:
            print("Välj rätt inmatningsvärden!")
        else: break

def remove_results(results):
    print("Radera resultat")
    print("-"*30)
    temp_list = []
    remover = input("Vems resultat vill du radera? ")
    for row in results:
        if remover not in row["namn"]:
            temp_list.append(row)
        else:
            pass
    print(temp_list)
```

Comment: try deep.copy() https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/